# How to always print exception to stdout even if the exception is caught?

Tags: java

I am debugging cause of a failure in a fairly large application but the code swallows the exception and WebLogic only prints transaction failure message without any stack trace. Is there any way to always print stack trace of exceptions even if the exception is caught?

I am using WebLogic 12c. Is there a way to always print stack trace for exceptions in a particular package? It will be great if this is a JVM argument.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2153830

Comment: If you have a commercial license, you can try setting up Java Mission Control to record stack trace of exception when it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than inspecting the log file produced by WebLogic, which can be tedious, if you can attach a remote debugger, or have the project on-hands, modern IDEs offer the possibility to set breakpoints on exceptions.
For example, in IntelliJ IDEA you can set it via

[image]

You can then conditionally enable them.

[image]

Comment: Exception breakpoint is useful while debugging using an IDE. Have to see some plugin is available that can log such exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is printed only if the code prints it. So if it is your code that swallows exception then you will need to fix your problem and just print the stacktrace if it wasn't. If it is not your code then it depends what the code does, and if it doesn't print the exception then there is nothing you can do. However, Weblogic as most other mature applications usually always report the problem and usually err on a side of safety, which means they usually print too much rather then not enough. But they usually print into log files and not into "system.err". With logs you have a great deal of control of what is printed. Logs have levels such as "DEBUG", "INFO" etc. Meaning that if you change your level to more detailed level (for example from "INFO" to "DEBUG" or "TRACE" or "ALL") all of a sudden you will see your log files contain much more info. Read on changing log level in Weblogic and find out all its log files. I strongly doubt that Weblogic really does not print some stacktrace that may be of any use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static void ex() {
  try {
    String x = null;
    x.length();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
}
```